# Filtering dataview from textbox VB

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i have a dgvw in my winform . I have a textbox to search/filter the dgvw.I tried a lots of code to filter the dgvw.But each one came up with different problems.Now,i am trying to use this code :

```
Private Sub searcgcon_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles searcgcon.TextChanged
TryCast(userdatagrid.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("Name LIKE '{0}%' OR Name LIKE '% {0}%'", searcgcon.Text)
```

I applied this code without understanding . Now it gives me an error saying : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I know i missed something.e.g. In the textchange event i applied this code, bu t as the code mentions "Userdatagrid.Datasource,DataTable",i did not declare/setup a datatable within the textchange event.Moreover,the code has """Name LIKE '{0}%' OR Name LIKE "".now here, is "NAME" the name of my db's column ?(i have multiple columns)
Now on my form's load event,the dgvw loads data from a sql db.Here's the code :

```
 Private Sub Contact_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from Contacts", con)
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim table As New DataTable
    adapter.Fill(table)
    userdatagrid.DataSource = table
```

So, i just wanna know:
1. what am i missing ? 
2. the code that i'm using to filter, is it the right code/solution ?
3. As mentioned, i have multiple columns in my db/dgvw,so how do i configure the filtering code to search in all the columns ?
4. About the USERDATAGRID.DATASOURCE,DATATABLE..i mentioned i did not set up any datatable within the textchane event , so can any one guide me what to do ?

Comment: What you are missing is that, when you get a `NullRefereenceException`, you supposed to start by checking all the current references to see which one is `Nothing`.

Comment: what do i need to do sir?any line of code that i need to write?

Comment: You need to learn how to debug.  Unlike many, [this beginners tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/vbNet.html) has a chapter on debugging.

Comment: i know that ...so just trying to understand which object i left as a null ? is there any way to know it ? i debugged but on form load the entire code in the text change event gives me the exception..Taht's odd..why does it happen on form load ?

Comment: `I applied this code without understanding` You should never use code you dont understand.  `TryCast` can fail and you are not checking.  You could skip that by making the `DataTable` a form level object.. I am pretty sure the problem is in the Form Load.  Set a breakpoint on the last line - it probably never gets there.  You `con` object seems to not be initialized or open.